# How can you dynamically slice an array in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, slice

I have a photo gallery that includes images that will be continuously uploaded. The PHP array has been converted/encoded to a JSON array so that I can manipulate the data with JavaScript.

Ideally, I would like to click a button ("Next Set" in the CodePen example) and load the next set (of 2) thumbnail images. This is in an effort to not load all of the images at once, which could be hundreds.

Problem: I cannot figure out how to **dynamically** slice the array on click (next 5 images). I can of course load, say, 2 at a time:

```
myArray.slice(0,2);
myArray.slice(3,5);
```

However, this will not work because images will be continuously added to the gallery. Furthermore, I would have to have too many sets of the above to keep slicing 5 out at a time.

I have tried:

- Splitting the array into smaller arrays
- `for` loops and `$.each` loops

I essentially need to be able to move the start and end index of the slice by (for example) 2 on click. Right now it just keeps slicing the same two images because the slicing is not dynamic.

Here is my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/kmarmet/pen/WpWvjL)

Comment: Just keep track of the index in a global var and increment by five each click. Then `.slice(index, index + 5); index += 5;`

Comment: Or if you don't care about the original array (if you don't care if it gets sgrunk) you can use [**`splice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which cut items out from the array! Every time you call `.splice(0, 2)` you'll get different elements because the previous ones have been cut out from the original array!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks! I will have to try that. I tried .splice before but could not get it to work right away and got over focused on .slice(). Ill give it another go!

Comment: Just put in mind that in this case `splice` should always start with 0 (`.splice(0, amount)`)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks again! I found the shift() method works great for what I need. Do you happen to know if it would be better to use this method (.splice()) or the .shift() method, and why? I will, of course, test both.

Comment: `.shift` cut only one item from the begining of the array, to use it you need a loop to cut as many as you want! Using `.splice(0, amount)` will cut `amount` of items from the begining so no loop is needed! **If you'll need to loop through the result array of the `splice`ing** then use `shift` . **If you'll use the return array as a whole** then use `.splice`. One thing to mention is that `splice` is safer because(`[1, 2].splice(0, 10000) === [1, 2]`), in `shift` version you'll have to check if there still element in the array to see if you'll continue or not(otherwise undefineds ar returned)!

Comment: Plus with `splice` you could use `forEach` like this: `array.splice(0, amount).forEach(function(img) { /* use img here */});`! `push` is slightly better in performance!

Comment: @ibrahim Wow that is some great information! I am excited to try both methids. Splice sounds like it might actually work better because I can cut any amount of items I want and it starts from the right index each time. Can think of a reason I would need to worry about keeping the original array intact ......

Comment: `.splice` will cut items out from the array! Example; let the array be `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, `a.splice(0, 2)` will return `[1, 2]` and the array `a` will shrunk by 2 and becomes: `a = [3, 4, 5, 6]`, so the next `.splice(0, 2)` will return `[3, 4]` and so on! Since the array get shrunk each time, the splicing should begin from the index 0! You're probably confusing it with `.slice`, because `.slice` keep the array intact so `.slice(0, amount)` will always return the same items because the array remains the same! But using `.splice` or `.push` the array is constantly shrunk!

Comment: I think you may have wrote your comment before I updated my comment. I re read your original comment and understood it the second time. Sorry for that! Your a lifesaver ! 

Comment: No problem! You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want, but you can just keep track of where you were in the array and do a slice from there, like this:

```
var nextSet = myArray.slice(lastIndex, lastIndex + 2);
```

Replace your existing `click()` with this (including the declaration of `lastIndex`) to try it:

```
var lastIndex = 0
$('.button').click(function() {
  var nextSet = myArray.slice(lastIndex, lastIndex + 2);
  lastIndex += 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var li = $('<li/>').attr('role', 'menuitem').appendTo('.myList').append('<img src=' + nextSet[i] + '>');
  }
});
```

Note that I've moved the `slice()` line outside the `for` loop. There's no need to slice a new array for every iteration.

Here's a [CodePen using `.slice()`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrzVyP).

An alternate method is to use to `shift()` to peel off the first item in the array with each iteration:

```
var nextItem = myArray.shift()
```

This is destructive though (it removes the item from the original array), so you'll need to make a copy of the original array first if you want to use it for anything else. Replace your `click()` with:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var nextItem = myArray.shift();
    var li = $('<li/>').attr('role', 'menuitem').appendTo('.myList').append('<img src=' + nextItem + '>');
  }
});
```

Here's a [CodePen using `.shift()`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpqXyV).

Comment: Thank you! The .shift() method seems to be just what I was looking for! Again, thank you so much for that. Been working on this for SO long. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is simple i think. you do a slice and allways get back the same array

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let newArray1 = array.slice(0,2); // returns a new array
let newArray2 = array.slice(0,2); // returns the same new array

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i = i+2) {
  result = array.slice(i, i+2);
  console.log(result);
}
```